# Error with WebDriver code @test and @afterclass is not running

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
package HomePage;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

public class NewTest {

WebDriver cd= null;
WebDriverWait wait=null;

@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() {
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\\\selenium\\\\chromedriver.exe");
   ChromeDriver  cd=new ChromeDriver();
   cd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   cd.get("http://www.biharfoundation.in/");

}

  @Test

public void Class() {

   cd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"body\"]/div/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();

 }




 @AfterClass
  public void afterClass() {
      cd.close();

  }

 }
```

In this code, `@test` and `@afterclass` is not running.

Can any one tell me what is the problem behind this?

Comment: Please share exception and more details.

Answer (score 1):

In your test as well as in your `@AfterClass` you're trying to call the method of `cd` which is `null`. In your `@BeforeClass` you're doing `ChromeDriver cd=new ChromeDriver();` but this does not initialise your `WebDriver cd` field of `NewTest` class. It just creates a locally visible object that other methods do not know about.